# How can I get server statistics XML of Icecast?

Tags: icecast

I'm using Icecast 2.3.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

I want to display currently played song title and its artist name on Apache run on the same server as Icecast.

How can I get server statistics XML of Icecast as described at the following page?

http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.3.3/server-stats.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the XML representation, you'll either have to access `http://localhost:8000/admin/stats` with admin credentials or place a custom XSLT sheet in `/usr/share/icecast2/web`.

**For current versions of Icecast this should not be necessary, but if you want to deeply customize things, this is retained for reference.**
You can find **old and potentially outdated** example XSLT files here:

https://ruecker.fi/foss/icecast/xslt/

A file that produces XML output is here:

https://ruecker.fi/foss/icecast/xslt/rds-xml.xsl

All you need to do is edit the mountpoint name in the file to match the name of the mountpoint you want information for.

**Or you could just install the official Xiph.org package of latest Icecast:**

https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/Installing_latest_version_(official_Xiph_repositories)

As it provides a [JSON API](https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/server-stats.html#xslt). It can even be queried directly from within a web page without necessitating any server side code.

Comment: Your custom XSLT sheet (rds-xml.xsl) worked. Thank you.

Comment: That page is no longer available. I'm trying to figure out how to display a stats page. Do you have any info in regards to this?

Comment: The URLs work again, note that for a current version of Icecast this should not be necessary.